# I need to align 3 divs in the center of my page with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container and 3 divs inside it of equal width and I am trying to get the divs to align in the centre of the page with equal distance between them and also equal distance from the edge of the page.

```css
.container {
    display : flex;
    width : 60%;
}

.para {
    width : 33%;
    padding : 1em;
    border:.5px solid black;
    margin :1em;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
<div class ="para one">para one para one para one para one para one para one 
para one para one para one para one para one</div>

<div class ="para two">para two para two para two para two para two para two 
para two para two para two para two para two para two </div>

<div class ="para three">para three  para three para three para three para 
three para three para three para three para three para three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `justify-content: space-between/space-around/center;` to your `.container` css

Comment: firstly remove `width` from your container. It delimits flex layout. Then use `justify-content: space-between;` on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `justify-content: space-between;` to add equal space between the items

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.para {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: .5px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="para one">
    para one para one para one para one para one para one para one para one para one para one para one</div>

  <div class="para two">
    para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two </div>

  <div class="para three">
    para three para three para three para three para three para three para three para three para three para three</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Automatic margins for the parent and space-around for the flex items.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.para {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: .5px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="para one">para one para one para one para one para one para one para one para one para one para one para one</div>
  <div class="para two">para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two para two </div>
  <div class="para three">para three para three para three para three para three para three para three para three para three para three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;  /* takes full height so that it can align vertically  */
    justify-content: center; /* horizontal center */
    align-items: center;  /* vertical center */
    margin: 0 auto;   /* makes container in center  */

}
```